# iPhone: Using NSMutableURLRequest with NSTimer to handle connection timeout

Tags: iphone, objective-c

"Forced" to use sendSynchronousRequest (POST) for our application. Checking if "response" is nil (below) will catch a few of the connection errors that may occur, but I'd like to invoke a timer as well to cancel the request after about 20 s.  Not sure on how to do that and how to "wait" for time out. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
  data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    if(response == nil) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Connection error"
                                              delegate:nil 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert resignFirstResponder];
        [alert release];

    } ...
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:20.0];
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work (also according to other posts on this issue).

Comment: The timeoutInterval is not taken in account when using the POST method, has a fixed standard value (more than 1 minute)